# 'target' is a required option

Tags: svelte, dash.js

I am trying to add the [official control panel](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/tree/development/contrib/akamai/controlbar) to dash.js player using Svelte.

I've followed instructions from Readme, which are very simple - just a matter of adding some HTML, CSS and a .js file. But Svelte doesn't like something - I am getting several vague errors in debugger:

```
[HMR][Svelte] Unrecoverable HMR error in <PlayerControlPanel>: next update will trigger a full reload
Uncaught (in promise) Error: 'target' is a required option
```

Please see [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4a0c65734a6347229c3aa43929dd9859?version=3.57.0)

How should the control panel be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` specifies where a component constructed in client-side code is to be added ([see docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api)).

You can't just export a constructor from a component, a component always has the same signature. You probably should restructure the code to initialize the bar in `onMount` and add the component directly in markup instead of trying to construct it manually.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the phrase "You can't just export a constructor from a component, a component always has the same signature"? I can't export (invoke?) a constructor because then a component "should" or "will have" the same signature? Signature being what?

Comment: Signature refers to the expected arguments of a function/constructor. The export simply will not work as you may have intended. All function exports from a component only exist on an *instance* of said component. The thing you import from a component file is always a *component constructor* which, as noted, has the signature given by Svelte and detailed in the linked docs.